# How can I add 1 day to current date?

Tags: javascript

I have a current Date object that needs to be incremented by one day using the JavaScript Date object. I have the following code in place:

```
var ds = stringFormat("{day} {date} {month} {year}", { 
    day: companyname.i18n.translate("day", language)[date.getUTCDay()], 
    date: date.getUTCDate(), 
    month: companyname.i18n.translate("month", language)[date.getUTCMonth()], 
    year: date.getUTCFullYear() 
});
```

How can I add one day to it?

I've added +1 to `getUTCDay()` and `getUTCDate()` but it doesn't display 'Sunday'
for `day`, which I am expecting to happen.

Comment: What do you mean by "add +1"?  Do you need the next day or something else?

Comment: Does `date: (date.getUTCDate()+1)` not work (works for me)? It's possible that there is a naming conflict with `date` (as Date()-Object _and_ as Object-Key. Have you tried calling the Date()-Object different?

Comment: currently it show up only as: <option value="2012-04-06">Sat 6 Apr 2012</option><option value="2012-04-07"> 7 Apr 2012</option>, no "Sunday 7 Apr 2012"

Comment: So it's not the `7 Apr` you need (what is 'add next day' to me), it's the `Sunday`. Remember to add the `+1` both in `day:` and `date:` (or, as the current answer mentions, before).

Answer (score 448, accepted):

To add one day to a date object:

```
var date = new Date();

// add a day
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Comment: See duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/javascript-date-increment-question.  This answer is good, but does not account for DST.  There are 2 days of the year that do not have 24 hours.

Comment: @Jess—it depends on how you want changes over DST represented. The question asked how to add one to the date, that's exactly what the above answer does. Adding 24 hours doesn't necessarily increment that date, adding one to the local date using [*setDate*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.36) always does.

Comment: Here is what I mean.  Incrementing March 10:  `var a = new Date("2013-03-10T00:00:00.000Z");` `a.setDate(a.getDate() + 1);`  `a.toISOString();` is `"2013-03-10T23:00:00.000Z"`.  This is a subtle case where the above function did not work for me.

Comment: Of course not! You start with a UTC time, then essentially convert it to local, add a day, then convert it back to UTC. So one day was added to the **local** date, but only 23 hrs the UTC time. If you add 1 to the UTC date, you'll get back 01:00:00 local time. That behaviour isn't unique to daylight saving, it's a consequence of using three different timezones.

Comment: Aha.  I didn't realize **[getDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)** was converting from UTC to local time.  `a.setUTCDate(a.getUTCDate() + 1);` <-- that works with Zulu dates.

Comment: what happens if 31+1 set ?

Comment: @Andy—then it will roll over to the 1st of the next month.

Comment: @Jess in which browser have you experienced the issue mentioned in your comment on Jan 13 '14 at 13:44? I've just tested in the freshest Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE11 and all of these gave `2013-03-10T00:00:00.000Z`. Furthermore, the `a.setUTCDate(a.getUTCDate() + 1);` produced the same result as well.

Comment: @Jess ignore my previous comment, please. I live in Europe, my current time zone is UTC+1, instead of the UTC+5 Indiana zone in which Zulu is. So the conversion is not problematic in my case, but the logic is still wrong, so I'll use the UTC version as you've suggested. RobG's answer adds 24 hours, but I need to increment the day number by 1 (regardless if it's 23 or 24 hours).

Comment: Hi @TamásBolvári.  Maybe you do not have daylight savings in your country or daylight savings begins on a different date.

Comment: @Jess I know I'm late to the party, but your comment on using `get`/`setUTCDate()` deserves to be an answer in its own right (and highly upvoted if it were).

Answer (score 85):

In my humble opinion the best way is to just add a full day in milliseconds, depending on how you factor your code it can mess up if you are on the last day of the month.

For example Feb 28 or march 31.

Here is an example of how I would do it:

```
var current = new Date(); //'Mar 11 2015' current.getTime() = 1426060964567
var followingDay = new Date(current.getTime() + 86400000); // + 1 day in ms
followingDay.toLocaleDateString();
```

Imho this insures accuracy

Here is another example. I do not like that. It can work for you but not as clean as example above.

```
var today = new Date('12/31/2015');
var tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
tomorrow.toLocaleDateString();
```

Imho `this === 'POOP'`

So some of you have had gripes about my millisecond approach because of day light savings time. So I'm going to bash this out. First, Some countries and states do not have Day light savings time. Second Adding exactly 24 hours is a full day. If the date number does not change once a year but then gets fixed 6 months later I don't see a problem there. But for the purpose of being definite and having to deal with allot the evil `Date()` I have thought this through and now thoroughly hate Date. So this is my new Approach.

```
var dd = new Date(); // or any date and time you care about 
var dateArray =  dd.toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-').concat( dd.toISOString().split('T')[1].split(':') );
// ["2016", "07", "04", "00", "17", "58.849Z"] at Z
```

Now for the fun part!

```
var date = { 
    day: dateArray[2],
    month: dateArray[1],
    year: dateArray[0],
    hour: dateArray[3],
    minutes: dateArray[4],
    seconds:dateArray[5].split('.')[0],
    milliseconds: dateArray[5].split('.')[1].replace('Z','')
}
```

Now we have our Official Valid international Date Object clearly written out at Zulu meridian.
Now to change the date

```
dd.setDate(dd.getDate()+1); // this gives you one full calendar date forward
tomorrow.setDate(dd.getTime() + 86400000);// this gives your 24 hours into the future. do what you want with it.
```

Comment: Adding seconds/milliseconds won't work for daylight savings.

Comment: @Matt H where did you get that idea from. 
The time is set in UTC in milliseconds from 1970/01/01

Comment: It will be the following day in UTC time, yes, but not necessarily in local time. On Spring Forward day in the US, there are 25 hours in the day. So if you have e.g. 3/31/15 at 00:00 hours, and add 86400000 milliseconds, on Sprint Forward day, the local time would be 3/31/15 at 23:00 hours since there are 25 hours in that day.

Comment: you can see the effect like this: `var dte = Date.parse('2015-11-01');  console.log(dte); dte.setTime(dte.getTime() + 86400000 ); console.log(dte);`

Comment: The console will log Sunday midnight, then Sunday 23:00. Using toLocalDateString displays Sunday on both dates (set your timezone to Eastern US to see how that works)

Comment: @RobG That wasn't a solution, it was showing the poster how their solution would fail due to daylight savings time. Notice the first part of that comment "you can see the effect like this".

Comment: This is over-engineered. If you're having a problem like this use a library like moment or something to help make things easier.

Answer (score 52):

If you want add a day (24 hours) to current datetime you can add milliseconds like this:

```
new Date(Date.now() + ( 3600 * 1000 * 24))
```

Comment: Even `new Date(Date.now() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))`

Answer (score 19):

```
int days = 1;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now() + days*24*60*60*1000);
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRjxy?editors=001)

```js
var days = 2;
var newDate = new Date(Date.now()+days*24*60*60*1000);

document.write('Today: <em>');
document.write(new Date());
document.write('</em><br/> New: <strong>');
document.write(newDate);
```

Comment: Adding one day of milliseconds fails because not all days are 24 hours long in places that observe daylight saving. E.g. Chile ends daylight saving at midnight on the start of 14 May 2017. Clocks will wind back from midnight to 23:00. So adding 24 hours to 2017-05-13 00:00:00 will produce 2017-05-13 23:00:00, and the date doesn't change (some browsers will do it at exactly midnight, others one millisecond after). :-(

Answer (score 16):

simply you can do this

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
console.log(date);
```

now the `date` will be the date of tomorrow. here you can add or deduct the number of days as you wish.

Comment: This helped me today Thanks! upvote for sure

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by [jpmottin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2971820/jpmottin) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674539/incrementing-a-date-in-javascript), here's the one line code:

```js
var dateStr = '2019-01-01';
var days = 1;

var result = new Date(new Date(dateStr).setDate(new Date(dateStr).getDate() + days));

document.write('Date: ', result); // Wed Jan 02 2019 09:00:00 GMT+0900 (Japan Standard Time)
document.write('<br />');
document.write('Trimmed Date: ', result.toISOString().substr(0, 10)); // 2019-01-02
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is function you can use to add a given day to a current date in javascript.

```
function addDayToCurrentDate(days){
  let currentDate = new Date()
  return new Date(currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + days))
}

// current date = Sun Oct 02 2021 13:07:46 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
// days = 2

console.log(addDayToCurrentDate(2))
// Mon Oct 04 2021 13:08:18 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Function gets date and count days to add to passed date
function addDays(dateTime, count_days = 0){
  return new Date(new Date(dateTime).setDate(dateTime.getDate() + count_days));
}

// Create some date
const today = new Date("2022-02-19T00:00:00Z");

// Add some days to date
const tomorrow = addDays(today, 1);

// Result
console.log("Tomorrow => ", new Date(tomorrow).toISOString());
// 2022-02-20T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 1):

//It is very simple

let d = new Date("22 Apr 2023");

d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

console.log(d);

Answer (score -1):

Below is an example of how to implement adding 1 day to current date using the `addDays` function from the `date-fns` library.

```js
import { addDays } from 'date-fns';

const tomorrow = addDays(new Date(Date.now()), 1);
```

[Resource Documentation date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns)

Answer (score -1):

For those dayjs fans, you can do this.

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

const date = dayjs().add(1, 'day');
```

This will allow you to pass in other options like: day, week, month, quarter, year.

See this documentation:
https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/add

Answer (score -5):

```
currentDay = '2019-12-06';
currentDay = new Date(currentDay).add(Date.DAY, +1).format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: What is this? Are you using a library?