# JavaScript setDate() returns Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date

So, I have this code :

```
$('#end_date').click(function() 
{
    var start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var duration = parseInt($('#duration').val());

    var end_date = new Date();
    end_date.setDate(start_date + duration);

    $('#end_date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', end_date));
});
```

Which, I believe, should take a start date from the form, and add some days (duration) in it, and the show the output in the other text field. However, the result I got is always NaN-NaN-NaN, or simply Invalid Date if I remove the formatting.

However :

```
$('#end_date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', start_date));
```

works just fine. So I don't think the problem lies in the 3rd line. And now I confused. Any pointer to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, let's just [check the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)...

Comment: I think you'll be able to use the linked doc to fix your code, but beware another pitfall : always precise the radix when using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), because `parseInt('09')` is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setDate` just sets the day of the month, and you could use `setFullYear` and `setMonth` or you can do this.

```
$('#end_date').click(function() 
{
    var start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var duration = parseInt($('#duration').val());

    var end_date = new Date();
    end_date.setDate(start_date.getMilliseconds() + duration.getMilliseconds());

    $('#end_date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', end_date));
});
```

Hoping that start_Date and duration are returning milliseconds.

Comment: ahh yeah, setMonth, should've use that instead. Thanks!

Comment: This will not work (i) duration is a number, numbers do not have `.getMilliseconds` (ii) `.getMilliseconds` returns milliseconds portion of the specified date, not the number of milliseconds from the unix epoch.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9989382/901048), you should instead try:

```
end_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `setDate` only sets the day in the month, you could do this :

```
var duration = parseInt($('#duration').val(), 10); // don't forget the radix!
var end_date = new Date();
end_date.setTime(start_date.getTime()); // makes end_date a copy of start_date
end_date.setDate(start_date.getDate() + duration); // changes the day of the month (and recomputes months and years)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#end_date').click(function() 
{
    var start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var duration = parseInt($('#duration').val());

    var end_date = new Date();
    end_date.setTime(start_date.getTime() + (duration*24*60*60*1000));//convert duration to miliseconds

    $('#end_date').val($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', end_date));
});
```

this should work, add duration to the time of start_date and set that Time to end_date