# Date, day, month and year increment by clicking nextdate button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am increasing and decreasing date in my application by clicking nextDay and previousDay, date is incrementing But once it reached the month end like 31, 30, 29(feb), 28(feb) then it should change the month as well as date also. But its keep on incrementing. Till now i have tried with below code

```
   var today = new Date();
   var days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday",
                 "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
   var months = ["January","February","March",
                 "April","May","June","July","August",
                 "September","October","November","December"];
   var nextDate = 0;
```

function set_todayDate()
{

```
document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = 
                        ""+days[today.getDay()]+",
                       "+months[today.getMonth()]+" 
                      "+today.getDate()+" 
                     "+today.getFullYear();
```

}

For next date and previous date, Just I am increasing and decreasing variable

```
      function nextDateMethod(){

        nextDate++;

    document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = ""+days[today.getDay()
      +dayIncrement]+ 
        ", "+months[today.getMonth()]+" 
      "+(today.getDate()+dayIncrement)+""+today.getFullYear();
    }



function prevDate(){
       nextDate--;

document.getElementById("todaysDate").
   innerHTML = months[today.getMonth()]+", 
     "+(today.getDate()+nextDate)+" "+today.getFullYear();
   }
```

Please anybody help me

Comment: Your basic problem is how to add 1 day to a date, which already has an answer here: [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date/9989458#9989458).

Comment: Be precise about the question! If you are expecting the specific output format then clearly mention in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
if (!Date.now) {
  Date.now = function() {
    return new Date().getTime();
  }
}
var theDate = Date.now();

document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)

document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener("click", function() {
  theDate -= 86400000;
  document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)
})
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", function() {
  theDate += 86400000;
  document.getElementById('date').innerText = getTheDate(theDate)
})

function getTheDate(getDate) {
  var days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
  ];
  var months = ["January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
    "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var theCDate = new Date(getDate);
  return days[theCDate.getDay()] + ', ' + theCDate.getDate() + '-' + months[theCDate.getMonth()] + '-' + theCDate.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<div id="date" style="height:100px; width:300px;">
</div>
<button id="prev">
  <</button>
    <button id="next">></button>
```

Comment: Sir its working good.. Thanks a lot.. Actually I was looking for this format.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped! :)

Comment: Really it helped me lot.. :-)

Comment: Code only answers aren't helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your answer fixes it.

Comment: I actually took a different approach and gave him/her a solution. I didn't really solve the issue I took a detour. And my code was short and simple so I didn't think an explanation was necessary. I will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Try this(Below is the running sample):

```js
var today = new Date();
 date = today.getDate();
 month= today.getMonth();
year= today.getFullYear();
month = month+1;

$("#Prev").click(function(){
   date = date -1;
  if(date<1){
  month = month -1;
    if(month == 0){
      year = year -1;
      date = 31;
      month = 12;
      } else{
      if(month == 2){
      date = 28
      } else if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
       date = 31
      } else{
       date = 30
      }
      }
  }
  $("#displayDate")[0].innerHTML = date + "/" +  month + "/" + year;
});

$("#Next").click(function(){
   date = date + 1;
  if(date>28 && month == 2){
    date = 1;
    month = 3;
 } 
  if( date> 30 && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)){
  date = date +1;
    month = month +1;
  } else  if (date> 31){
  date =1; 
    month = month+1;
    if(month >12){
    year = year +1;
      month= 1; 
      date = 1;
    }
  }  
  
  $("#displayDate")[0].innerHTML = date + "/" +  month + "/" + year;
});

$("#displayDate")[0].innerHTML = date + "/" +  month + "/" + year;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="Prev">Prev</button><div id="displayDate"></div><button id="Next">Next</button></div>
```

**Note:** Condition for [Leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) is not added yet let me know if it is the expected then answer I will add that too.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your code should automatically update month when date has reached 30 or 31 or so on. You are taking the getDate() function and this returns a number. Then, you are increasing or decreasing it by 1. It will simply act like `var x=y+z`. You will either have to manipulate the `Date` object or have to manually configure the months and leap year etc. system. 
I checked the Date Reference object at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp and it seems you don't have built in fucntion like addDays() as in C#. So I guess you will have to manually implement the calender rule. 
And also, please mention where you declared and initialized `nextDate`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function to add any number of days to a given date, the trick is using the setDate method of the date object

```
function addDays(date, days) {
    var result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}
```

EDIT : since the date class is mutable you can also add a method to ease future use

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
    return this;
};
```

Comment: interesting! Did not know that this works. Indeed the date object is smart enough to recognize, if the date you want to set is larger than it's month's number of days.

Comment: ya I find the documentation rather lacking myself, this is definetly not a very intuitive structure @AntonHarald

Answer (score 0):

There is a very neat library, called moment.js, which handles a lot of date manipulation tasks and offers various convenient ways to display dates. The webpage and the documentation are very well done, so i think it's worth looking at their effort.

This is how the requested job of increasing the day of a date would look in moment.js:

```
var new_date_str = moment().add(1, 'days').format("dd, MMMM, D, YYYY");
```

see this fiddle for a full running example: https://jsfiddle.net/me6pdk8L/2/