# How to Pre-Set Dates/Times using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want authors to be able to schedule posts to be published from Pre-Set Dates/Times using a select box.

I use a JavaScript code that allow the authors to schedule a post in 1 hour, Tomorrow 8 am, Tomorrow after lunch, Tonight, Next monday or Next month.

The problem is that if the current date for example is November 30, 2016, when I select the "Tomorrow 8 am" option the date change to November 31, 2016

NOT TO

December 01, 2016

The problem occurs at the end of each month.

I do not know how to resolve it.

Please, help.

The JavaScript Code is:

```
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    $(function () {

        // Get next coming weekday. 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...
        Date.prototype.getNextWeekDay = function (d) {
            if (d) {
                var next = this;
                next.setDate( this.getDate() - this.getDay() + 7 + d );
                return next;
            }
        }

        // Prepend leading zero if < 10. i.e 9 -> 09
        function pad(n) {
            return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
        }

        // Add hours
        Date.prototype.addHours= function(h){
            this.setHours(this.getHours()+h);
            return this;
        }

        if($('#timestampdiv:visible').length == 0) {

            // Setup fuzzy items
            var fuzzy = [langstrings.inoneour, langstrings.tomorroweightam, langstrings.tomorrowafterlunch, langstrings.tonight, langstrings.nextmonday, langstrings.nextmonth, langstrings.reset];

            // Create new select box
            $('<select class="fuzzy-later"><option value="">'+langstrings.postpone+'...</option></select>').insertBefore(".save-timestamp   ");

            // Add the fuzzy options
            for (var i = 0; i < fuzzy.length; i++) {
                $('.fuzzy-later').append('<option value="'+fuzzy[i]+'">'+fuzzy[i]+'</option>');
            }

            // Update date and time when select box changes
            $('.fuzzy-later').on('change', function(e) {

                // Get current date
                var now = new Date();

                e.preventDefault();

                var fuzzyChoice = $('.fuzzy-later').find(":selected").text();

                switch (fuzzyChoice) {
                    case langstrings.inoneour :
                        $('#jj').val(pad(now.getDate()));
                        $('#hh').val(now.addHours(1).getHours());
                        $('#mn').val(now.addHours(1).getMinutes());
                        $('#mm option').eq(now.getMonth()).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.tomorroweightam :
                        $('#jj').val(pad(parseInt(now.getDate())+1));
                        $('#hh').val('08');
                        $('#mn').val('00');
                        $('#mm option').eq(now.getMonth()).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.tomorrowafterlunch :
                        $('#jj').val(pad(now.getDate()+1));
                        $('#hh').val('13');
                        $('#mn').val('00');
                        $('#mm option').eq(now.getMonth()).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.tonight :
                        $('#jj').val(pad(now.getDate()));
                        $('#hh').val('22');
                        $('#mn').val('00');
                        $('#mm option').eq(now.getMonth()).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.nextmonday :
                        $('#jj').val(pad(now.getNextWeekDay(1).getDate()));
                        var nextmondaymonth = pad(now.getNextWeekDay(1).getMonth());
                        $('#mm option').eq(nextmondaymonth).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.nextmonth :
                        var nextmonth = $('#mm').find(":selected").index() + 1;
                        $('#mm option').eq(nextmonth).prop('selected', true);
                        break;
                    case langstrings.reset :                        
                        $('.cancel-timestamp').trigger('click');
                        $('#mm').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                        break;
                }

            });

        }

    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: See [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date/9989458#9989458).

Answer (score 1):

You are simply pulling the date from the Date object and adding 1 with no checks at all regarding the end of the month. The Date object provides a method for addressing this. Use the .getDate() method as you are, but rather than just dumping it to the output, use the .setDate() method with the date you just got + 1. Then you can proceed to use the Date object as you are.