# How to set a future date and time

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, nativescript

I am creating a todo app in nativescript using this plugin by Eddy https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-calendar.

The issue i have is with the date option, precisely startDate and endDate.

i am trying to set the day of the event e.g November 31, 2016 and the time it starts e.g 8:00am.
In the doc, it is done like this:

```
//an Event for now + 1 hour, lasting 1 hour.
startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (60*60*1000)),
endDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (2*60*60*1000))
```

i have tried diffrent ways to achieve what i need but none works.

My latest trial is shown below and it gives the error getTime() is not a function:

```
startDate: new Date(Date(viewModel.scheduleDay).getTime() + (60*60*1000)),
startDate: new Date(Date(viewModel.scheduleDay).getTime() + (60*60*1000)),
```

i tired just to get for same day, it worked using this:

```
startDate: new Date(new Date().setTime(viewModel.scheduleTime)),
endDate: new Date(new Date().setTime(viewModel.scheduleTime))
```

What i need to do is set the date and time for the event to start.

Thanks.

Comment: *"i have tried diffrent ways to achieve what i need but none works."* The code just above that absolutely sets `startDate` to "now plus one hour" and `endDate` to "now plus two hours". Please add a **runnable** [mcve] to the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) so we can help you.

Comment: I am not use if i fully get what you need me to do... I got that code from the documentation for the plugin i am using. It's just an example of how it was used. here  is the link to the page with the full info. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-calendar you will find it under createEvent section. Thanks

Comment: Use "edit" to edit your question, then click the `<>` toolbar button to create a Stack Snippet. This opens a jsFiddle-like editor. Add any scripts you need to add via the External Libs button, add your code and markup, and make sure it runs and demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: Okay, i get it now. And i tried to do as you said, but it wont really be any useful. I tested my code well i know beyond measure that the problem will be solved if i know how to set the future date and time. Also i am building a mobile app not a web app, so using that js fiddle like interface will not run the app. The framework i am using allows me to use js, css and xml to build cross platform mobile apps. https://www.nativescript.org/ Thanks again.

Comment: Use moment.js and call it a day :p

Comment: Will check out moment.js thanks @Brad Martin

Comment: You really don't need a library to create a date for a specific date and time, nor to increment it by some amount. See [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date/9989458#9989458). The same method can be used to increment or decrement any part of a date.