# Date now + 1 month in nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pug, ejs

this is my code in ejs file :

```
<select class="form-control track-change input-lg" data-track="deadline" name="Deadline" id="Deadline" placeholder="Deadline">
    <option value="0" class="task-option project-option default-option" selected="selected" style="display: block;">No deadline</option>
    <option value="12" class="task-option" >12 Hours</option>
    <option value="24" class="task-option project-option" style="display: block;">24 Hours</option>
    <option value="48" class="task-option">2 Days</option>
    <option value="72" class="task-option project-option" style="display: block;">3 Days</option>
    <option value="168" class="task-option project-option" style="display: block;">1 Week</option>
    <option value="336" class="project-option" style="display: none;">2 Weeks</option>
    <option value="504" class="project-option" style="display: none;">3 Weeks</option>
    <option value="731" class="project-option" style="display: none;">1 Month</option>
</select>
```

When a user chooses 12 Hours I need to save the date now +12 Hours in MySQL,  and if choose 2 Days I need to save the date now + 2 Day from now, etc.

How can I do it using nodejs or ejs (jade) or javascript? I need just Date code not sql query ...any help please?

Comment: Where is the code you've tried?

Comment: when u see the value for example in 12 Hours the value is 12 when i save it in mysql its return a 30-11-2001 ..so i dot try anything so far ...any idea?

Comment: Incrementing any date part is pretty much the same, see [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date/9989458#9989458).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you can call a function every time you select the option, you can do this

```
function deadlineChanged(hours){
   let newTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   ///do whatever you want to do with the new time
}
```

if you want to convert it to mysql string, you can use this function

```
function formatdate(date) {
if (date instanceof Date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    return year + "-" + (month >= 10 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + (day >= 10 ? day : '0' + day);
} else {
    return date;
}
}
```

Comment: Vs `now = new Date(); now.setHours(now.getHours() + moreHours)`.

Comment: the sql row must be a Date ???

Comment: Hi @RobG is it faster that way? I never have the chance to compare both of them..

Comment: @FaresAlkhwaja see my updated answer.. it returns a string in YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: thnx alot for your help  ^_^

Comment: any idea for how to add html tag like stackoverflow when i choose for example a javascript tag ?

Comment: @RobG i'm sorry i think you not get my question... i need to write a code in html do a tags things like we do in StackOverFlow  ^_^