# Angularjs How to get all dates and days in a week

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to get all dates and days of a week in angularjs

```
<script>
        function startAndEndOfWeek(date) {
            date = "2019-02-26 00:00:00";   -- passing any date here       
            var now = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
            now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var monday = new Date(now);
            monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - monday.getDay() + 1);
            var sunday = new Date(now);
            sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate() - sunday.getDay() + 7);
            return [monday, sunday];
        }
      //alert(startAndEndOfWeek(new Date(2019, 03, 28)).join('\n'));
        alert(startAndEndOfWeek().join('\n'));
    </script>
```

Result:   Mon Feb 25 2019 00:00:00
          Sun Mar 03 2019 00:00:00

But I want all dates and days of that week like 
Mon  Feb 25
Tue  Feb 26
..
..

so that i can bind it to the repeater below which will display dates and days in a table.

```
<body>
    <div ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
            <!--<div ng-repeat="day in weekDays">  {{day}} </div>-->
            <table ng-repeat="day in weekDays">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="lblDay">Date - Day: </label>{{day}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS- Get days of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008354/js-get-days-of-the-week)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have modified your function `startAndEndOfWeek`

```
function startAndEndOfWeek(date = "2019-02-26 00:00:00") {
    var now = date ? new Date(date) : new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return Array(7).fill('').map((_, i) => {
      var monday = new Date(now);
      monday.setDate(monday.getDate() - monday.getDay() + (i + 1));
      const day = monday.toDateString().split(' ')[0];
      const month = monday.getMonth() + 1;
      const date = monday.getDate();
      return day + ' ' + month + '/' + date;
    });
  }

startAndEndOfWeek("2019-02-26 00:00:00")
```

make sure to collect all the dates for a week

Comment: Thxs for looking into it. Is there a way to get only Day  and month/date instead of full details like sun Mar 31 2019 00:00:00 GMT + ........

Comment: send me the format you want and i will edit the answer

Comment: Mon 3/28
...  which I want to bind it to the repeater so that I can display dates and days in a table cells.