# How to get past 7 days and next 7 days in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, days

I'm trying to get past 7 days and next 7 days date start data and end date using javascript date function.

For example : Today 31 march 2017 , When i click previous button, it will calculate from previous date ie: start and end date , (24 March 2017 to 30 March 2017) , again click previous (17 March 2017 to 23 March 2017)etcc..

Same thing will replicate for next button ..

I have tried the below things but its not working

```
 function getPreviousWeek(){
      ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount = ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount + 1;
      ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious  = (-6 * ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount);
      getByWeek();
}

 function getNextWeek(){
      ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount = ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount - 1;
      ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious  = (-6 * ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount);
      getByWeek();
}


function getByWeek(){   

      console.log("weekpreviouscount" + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount); //-6,-12,-18,-24
      console.log("weekprevious" + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious); //-6,-12,-18,-24
      var d2 = new Date(); // 31.01.2017
      var d1 = new Date(d2);
      d1.setDate(d2.getDate() - 1); // 30.01.2017
      var previousWeek = '';
      var current_day = '';

      console.log("d2date" + d1.getDate());
      console.log("week2" + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious)
      previousWeek = new Date(d1);
      previousWeek.setDate(d1.getDate() + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious); // 30-13=17

      current_day = new Date(d1); // 30.01.2017
      current_day.setDate(d1.getDate() + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious + 6); // 30-12+5=23

      console.log("currentdayprevious" + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious); //-6,-12,-18,-24

      var previousWeekUTCTimestamp = Math.floor(previousWeek.getTime() / 1000);
      var currentUTC = Math.floor(current_day.getTime() / 1000);

      console.log("previousWeekUTCTimestamp" + previousWeekUTCTimestamp);
      console.log("currentUTC" + currentUTC);

      var sinceUTC = previousWeekUTCTimestamp;
      var untilUTC = currentUTC;

}
```

Its first time comes correct 24-march 2017 to 30 march 2017 , next previous its comes 24-march to 18march2017

Any ideas ?please

Comment: Can you use external libraries? Using moment.js for all of this sort of thing will remove many headaches and potential bugs.

Comment: If you want the 17th of March through the 23rd of March but are currently getting the 18th through the 24th, why don't you just subtract one day from your calculation?

Comment: @MikeC: I'm getting confusing the logic , thats y asking help from any one

Comment: @Whelkaholism: I'm suffering to write the prev next logic ..some what i have confused here

Comment: Where is *ProHistoryCtrl* defined? What are the values for *weekPrevcount* and *weekPrevious*? Neither function takes any arguments, nor do they return any values. Please post a minimal, working example. Calculating a date that is plus or minus a fixed number of days is answered here: [*Add +1 to current date*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your Maths, you get the previous week by subtracting 6 for each week and then subtracting an extra 1.  This is fine for the first week where -6 -1 = -7, however for the second week this is (-6 * 2) - 1 = -13 but two weeks should be -14.  The code that is incorrect is:

```
ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious  = (-6 * ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount);

d1.setDate(d2.getDate() - 1);
```

A solution would therefore be:

```
 function getPreviousWeek(){
            ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount = ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount + 1;
            ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious  = (-7 * ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount);
            getByWeek();
}

 function getNextWeek(){
            ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount = ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount - 1;
            ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious  = (-7 * ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevcount);
            getByWeek();
}

function getByWeek(){   

    var d2 = new Date(); // 31.01.2017
    var d1 = new Date(d2);
    d1.setDate(d2.getDate()); // 30.01.2017
    var previousWeek = '';
    var current_day = '';

    previousWeek = new Date(d1);
    previousWeek.setDate(d1.getDate() + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious); // 30-13=17

    current_day = new Date(d1); // 30.01.2017
    current_day.setDate(d1.getDate() + ProHistoryCtrl.weekPrevious + 6); // 30-12+5=23

    var previousWeekUTCTimestamp = Math.floor(previousWeek.getTime() / 1000);
    var currentUTC = Math.floor(current_day.getTime() / 1000);

    var sinceUTC = previousWeekUTCTimestamp;
    var untilUTC = currentUTC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function. You don't need extra functions

```js
var btn = document.querySelector("button")

Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  this.setDate(this.getDate() + parseInt(days));
  return this;
};


function getDate(days) {
  var date = new Date().addDays(days);
  return date
}



btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var pastSevenDays = getDate(-7)
  var nextSevenDays = getDate(7)
  // only date
  console.log(pastSevenDays.toLocaleString().slice(0,10))
  console.log(nextSevenDays.toLocaleString().slice(0,10))
}, false)
```

```html
<button>Get Dates</button>
```