# Show all date between two date range in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to show all dates between two days.I can't do this.Please help..
This is my code...

```
 var Day = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var firstDate = new Date("2017-04-10");
var secondDate = new Date("2017-04-15");

var diffDays = (secondDate.getTime() - firstDate.getTime())/Day;
alert(diffDays);
for(var i=0;i<= diffDays ;i++)
{
   var d = new Date(firstDate  + i);
   alert(d);
}
```

Comment: Please look at your browser's console: it will display details of the syntax error and reference error in your code. Fix those and the code will run, though you shouldn't have a variable called `Date` given there is already a `Date` function, but in the code shown you don't actually do anything with the resulting dates - where should they be displayed?

Comment: edit my code. But it show first date only not increment the date

Comment: When in doubt what's happening, take baby steps. If you assign `firstDate + i` to a variable and inspect that, before you use the result value to create a new Date, the solution to your problem should be trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `i` variable is the *number of the day to display*.  Your `firstDate` variable is a `Date`.

This line:

```
var d = new Date(firstDate + i);
```

adds these together and tries to create a new `Date`.  Due to these being different types (a date and a number) type coercion comes into play (ie: the Date and the Number get converted to strings, and concatenated together).

Try this:

```
var DAY_IN_MS = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var theDate = new Date("2017-04-10");
var i = 5;

// Date + Number = Type Coercion!  Both objects will be converted to strings and concatenated together.
alert(theDate + i);

// The Date constructor doesn't care, and will work because it can get a date from the first part of the string.
alert(new Date(theDate + i));

// If you use `getTime()` you can get the numerical value of the Date, which you can use for arithmetic.
alert(theDate.getTime());

// By adding `i`, however, you are only adding a few milliseconds to the first date !!
alert(new Date(theDate.getTime() + i);

// Number + Number of days times milliseconds per day = success!
alert(new Date(theDate.getTime() + (i * DAY_IN_MS)));
```

I think you mean:

```
var d = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + (i * Day));
```

Comment: i attached the above code but it not working.Show only first date

Comment: Sorry I missed something.  Try this.

Comment: Good explanation, however adding one to a date should be done [*thusly*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date) since not all days are 24hrs long where daylight saving is observed. ;-)

Comment: @RobG thanks - this is intended as a simple solution to OPs broken code, not a lecture on date-based arithmetic ;)  Heaven forbid anybody mentions [timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY)...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, increment the right amount of milliseconds to `firstDate.getTime()` :

```
for(var i=0;i<= diffDays ;i++)
{
    firstDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + Day);
    console.log(firstDate);
}
```

Long answer, you have several things wrong in your code :

1. Here `var d = new Date(firstDate  + i);` you are adding to a Date object string representation the value of `i` in this case incremented on the loop.
2. You are then parsing this String into a new Date object, but Javascript only recognizes the date and ignores the appended number

You should either try to get the milliseconds of `firstDate` as you did for `diffDays` and then add `i * Day` (also consider renaming this variable to something else, maybe a `const DAY_IN_MS` or something).