# Show value in 5 days previous

Tags: javascript

I have 10 value like this ( I use new Date() to create it ) :

```
Wed Jun 14 2017 18:51:33 
Wed Feb 7 2017 18:51:33 
Wed Apr 10 2017 18:51:33 
Wed Jun 10 2017 18:51:33 
Wed Jun 1 2017 18:51:33 
....
```

How  can I get value of last 5 day

Comment: How you are creating them ?

Comment: See [*Add +1 to current date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date).

Answer (score 7):

you can get past dates by decrementing date you get from `new Date()` function.

check below code.

```
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
```

you can do date formatting in `yesterday` too.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript,

add dates to one array, iterate them

```
var datesArray = []; //add dates to this array
var lastfivedays = [];

datesArray.forEach(function(checkdate){
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var timeDiff = currentDate.getTime() - checkdate.getTime();
  var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
  if(diffDays == -5){ 
    lastfivedays.push(checkdate)  
  } 
});
```

lastfivedays array contains dates of last 5 day