# Uncaught TypeError: getFullYear is not a function

Tags: javascript, date

I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: date3.getFullYear is not a function"

I have a date variable in both SQL and JS format (passed from another function as arguments):

```
min1 - in SQL format. [Like - '2017-08-13 0:0:00']
mindate - in JS format. [Like - 'Sun Aug 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)' ]
```

I am using these variables to create a new date variable called 'date3'. I have tried the following:

```
var date2 = min1.split(' ')[0]; // should give me '2017-08-13'
date3 = new Date(date2);
```

AND,

```
var date3 = new Date();
date3 = mindate;
```

AND,

```
var date3 = mindate;
```

AND,

```
var Y = parseInt(min1.split(' ')[0].split('-')[0]);       // 2017
var M = parseInt(min1.split(' ')[0].split('-')[1]) - 1;   // 7
var D = parseInt(min1.split(' ')[0].split('-')[2]);       // 13
var date3 = new Date(Y,M,D);
```

And when I console.log the date3, it gives the correct date. But when I do a getFullYear() on date3, it gives the error: "Uncaught TypeError: getFullYear is not a function"

I have tried everything and nothing seems to work. (I even read some other similar questions, and some answers were saying its because 'date' is a 'moment' object, but I don't understand what it means and how it can help resolve this).

UPDATE:

Here's how I am using the getFullYear function. I have tried two things:

```
datestring = date3.getFullYear() + '-' + (date3.getMonth()+1) + '-' + (date3.getDate());
```

AND

```
var y = date3.getFullYear(),
m = date3.getMonth() + 1, // january is month 0 in javascript
d = date3.getDate();
```

Am using this inside a 'for' loop, and the date3 was created just above the loop as follows:

```
var date3 = new Date(Y,M,D);
console.log(date3);

for (k=1; k<=x; k++) {

    var y = date3.getFullYear(),
    m = date3.getMonth() + 1, // january is month 0 in javascript
    d = date3.getDate();
    var pad = function(val) { var str = val.toString(); return (str.length < 2) ? "0" + str : str};
    datestring = [y, pad(m), pad(d)].join("-");
    console.log("DATESTRING", datestring);

    divCode += '<div class="swiper-slide" id="_' + datestring + '" data-hash="' + datestring + '"><b>' +datestring+ '</b><br><br>' +tableCode+ '</div>';

    // Incrementing date by 1
    date3 = date3.setDate(date3.getDate() + 1);


}
```

Comment: Update the code to show the exact usage of `date3.getFullYear()`

Comment: OK, so its working fine outside the for loop.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see any for loop in your code...

Comment: I am sorry, I updated it..

Comment: Now when we have all the information we can actually help :) Note that without looking at your code it was impossible to do so.

Comment: Yes, true :) thanks a lot..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151843/discussion-between-user3001859-and-dekel).

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems this is actually a duplicate of [*Add +1 to current date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date). Note also that "2017-08-13" will be parsed as UTC (mostly) so will appear to be the wrong date sometimes if the host offset is not +0000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setDate` method works inplace on the object, and the return value of the function is the timestamp of the new date.

When you did:

```
date3 = date3.setDate(date3.getDate() + 1);
```

in your function, the `date3` is now an integer (and not a Date() object), so basically what your code does now is `1502742691133.getFullYear()`, and this is wrong.

You don't need to set the value of `setDate()` to `date3`. Just do:

```
date3.setDate(date3.getDate() + 1);
```