# Javascript Date +15 Days

Tags: javascript, date

I want this day to be 25 days from now, and it needs to correspond with normal workday measurements. Saturdays, Sundays and Holidays need to be removed. I've tried using Google sheets and javascript:

Here is what I have.

```
function Calendar() {
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var month = new Array();
month[0] = "01";  
month[1] = "02";
month[2] = "03";
month[3] = "04";
month[4] = "05";
month[5] = "06";  
month[6] = "07";
month[7] = "08";
month[8] = "09";
month[9] = "10";
month[10] = "11";
month[11] = "12";  
  var monthnum = month[now.getMonth()];
  var weekday = new Array();
  weekday[0] = "Sunday";
  weekday[1] = "Monday";
  weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
  weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
  weekday[4] = "Thursday";
  weekday[5] = "Friday";
  weekday[6] = "Saturday";

  var day = weekday[now.getDay()];

  var date = now.getDate();

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Schedule");
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();
  var destination = sheet.getRange(last, 1);
  var format = sheet.getRange(10, 1, 1, 7);
  var insertdate = sheet.getRange(last, 2);
  var insertday = sheet.getRange(last, 1)



  sheet.insertRowAfter(last);
  sheet.deleteRow(7)
  insertdate.setValue(monthnum + "/" + date + "/" + year);
  insertday.setValue(day)


  Logger.log(monthnum + "/" + date + "/" + year + " " + day)
}
```

Comment: what don't you add `date` in month array ? It would be easy to work with it

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: you mean you want to make sure that in 25 days the day will be Monday - Friday?

Comment: @StevenBlack I want the new date that is entered to be a day 25 days from now

Comment: ohh! the date could be greater than 6! I see

Comment: Write an example of the result which you need

Comment: @StevenBlack what?

Comment: @FerhadOthman Todays entry will be Wednesday <-(Left Cell)|(Right Cell)-> 11/1/2017. However I want the new cell that is made each day to be a day 25 days from now so  Saturday | 11/25/2017

Comment: Do you want all days between first and last in array or just the first and the last day?

Comment: @FerhadOthman No I just want the new day that is created to be 25 days ahead.

Comment: @BrendanMan33 Check the example below if that is what you wanted

Comment: If you want the weekday to remain the same, you must add a multiple of 7 days. 25 doesn't fit that criterion.

Comment: The JavaScript Date constructor will adjust out of range values for you.  So if today was Dev 25 2017 you could just add 15 days and construct a "Dec 40th 2017" date and JS will fix that up for you into Jan 9th 2018

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of [*many other questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+add+business+days) about adding business days.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to do it, but the easily one is: `86400000` is one day

```
86400000= 24 Hours * 60 Min * 60 Seconds * 1000 Milliseconds
```

Here is an example which may help you:

```js
var first = new Date();
var last = new Date(new Date(first).getTime() + (86400000 * 25));
var now = new Date(); now.setDate(now.getDate() + 25);
console.log(first);
console.log(last);
console.log(now);
```

Comment: This one actually worked var now = new Date();
  now.setDate(now.getDate() + 25);

Comment: Disregard my last message. Using the code I posted worked. Give it a try

Comment: Please give more details, then can I help you

Comment: No this one //                                                                                                  
    var now = new Date();                                       
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 25);

Comment: One day is not always 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed. You should add days, not time. See [*Add +1 to current date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/add-1-to-current-date), which gives the basic algorithm for adding or subtracting any number of days.

Comment: @RobG Go learn first mathematics not Programming, and see all the answers of your link, and read my answer carefully!!:)

Comment: @FerhadOthman— if your intention is to show that adding ms does not necessarily give the same result as adding days (i.e. *last* is not equal to *now*), you should explain that in your answer. Otherwise you're depending on the example crossing a daylight saving boundary (it doesn't for me), that the OP will notice the difference and understand why.