# Compare date not working with toLocaleDateString() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

When i am trying to compare the two dates using date.toLocaleString() it is not giving the correct answer for some months date.

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 1000*3600*24);
if(date1.toLocaleDateString() < date2.toLocaleDateString())
{
  alert("Correct");
}
else
{
  alert("Incorrect");
}
```

Can anyone have solution for this.

Comment: Why are you comparing strings when you can compare Dates directly using `date1 < date2`? The output of *toLocaleString* is **entirely** implementation dependent, so consistent results of comparisons is extremely unlikely. Also see [*How can I add 1 day to current date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/how-can-i-add-1-day-to-current-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toLocaleDateString` for todays date is `2018-2-21` where as for the month november, it is `2018-11-21`. So in terms of string comparisons, november month will be considered to have a lesser value than todays date.

> Use Timestamp to compare dates.

```
var date1 = new Date(),
    date2 = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 1000*3600*24)

if(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime()) {
  alert("Correct");
} else {
  alert("Incorrect");
}
```

Comment: "*toLocaleDateString for todays date is…*" entirely implementation dependent and different in different hosts. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, didn't know that. Ty for the comment. Feel free to edit the answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```js
var date1 = new Date();
    var date2 = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 1000*36000*24);
    if(date1.getTime() < date2.getTime())
    {
      alert(""+date1+"Smaller then \n "+date2);
    }
    else
    {
      alert(""+date1+"\n "+date2);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why is jQuery included? A good answer should include why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.