# I am Working on JavaScript Dates and i am stuck with converting month into week start date and end date

Tags: javascript, date

1. I have a month start date and end date,(2020-09-01) and (2020-09-30)
2. i need to convert into week1 start date and week1 end date.
3. assume week = Monday to Saturday
4. like wise i need all weeks for a month
5. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: First Week 2020-09-01 To 2020-09-07
Second Week 2020-09-08 To 2020-09-14
Third Week 2020-09-15 To 2020-09-21
Fourth Week 2020-09-22 To 2020-09-28
Fifth Week 2020-09-29 To 2020-09-30

Comment: i have added 7 days for 1st date,

Comment: You say weeks are Monday to Sunday, but then define the weeks of the month as starting on Tuesday (because 1 Sep 2020 is a Tuesday). You should put additional information in the question, not in comments. Your list of week days is very important as it answers a number of questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) to get the day of the week. Then use it as an offset to get the first week.

```
var date1 = new Date('September 1, 2020 03:24:00')
var nextMonday = new Date(date1.getTime()+1000*60*60*24*(8-date1.getDay()))
```

Comment: `new Date('September 1, 2020 03:24:00')` is not a good way to create a date, `new Date(2020, 8, 1,  3, 24)` is much preferred. Not all days are 24 hours long where daylight saving is observed, so adding a day (or any number of days) should be done as for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989458/257182).