# How do I add 1 to a date in a query string with an onClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am trying to have previous day, current day, and next day buttons so for example, if I press the next button, it will take today's date, add one to today's date and show tomorrows information on the page.

My click handler looks like:

```
const nextHandler = () => {
    let resDate = new Date();
    let year = resDate.getFullYear();
    let day = new Date().getDate();
    let month = resDate.getMonth() + 1;

    if (month.toString().length < 2 || day.toString().length < 2) {
      month = ('0' + month).slice(-2);
      day = ('0' + day).slice(-2);
    }

    day = parseInt(day) + 1;
    let newDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    
    // newDate --> 2021-04-11
     history.push(`/dashboard?date=${newDate}`);
  };
```

When I click my next button I get taken to: `http://localhost:5000/reservations?date=2021-04-12` exactly as I would like. However, I am only able to add to the day once. How am I continuously able to update this query string?

Comment: Adding 1 to the day isn't a good way to add 1 day to a Date since it won't handle end of months. See [*How can I add 1 day to current date?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/how-can-i-add-1-day-to-current-date)

Answer (score 1):

You're only ever starting with `new Date();` on your second line so it'll only ever increment once. You'll have to read from the querystring a value to put in `new Date(VALUE);` if it's set so that it continues to remember. Here's a stackoverflow answer from something like that: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

You're code may look like:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const dateParam = urlParams.get('date');
let resDate = dateParam ? new Date(dateParam) : new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `nextHandler` is using today's date to increment rather than the date of the query string.

On the first click, `nextHandler` today's date to increment. But, the next click should start from the date in the query string.

I hope that solve your problem.