# How to validate End date which is less than the Start date in react and add error message in banner if the end date is less than start date in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc540.png)How to validate End date which is less than the Start date in react and add error message in banner if the end date is less than start date in react.

I have edit profile page there I should display the error message in the banner to say like end date cannot be less than start date.

Note: using react-datepicker component

Start date: 05-25-2021
End date: 05-19-2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `minDate` in end date datepicker putting start date? Something like:

```
 <DatePicker //<-- this is the end date picker
    selected={endDate}
    onChange={date => setEndDate(date)}
    minDate={new Date(startDate)} //<-- here put as minDate the startDate so user cannot select a date less than startDate
    placeholderText="Select a date"
/>
```

Comment: I am using same <DatePicker> component for both start date and date end, in that case how can we pass minDate ?

Comment: Conditional minDate based on what date user is setting. If is startDate then minDate is 1899 (for instances), else minDate is startDate. Make sense?

Comment: Yes correct but you could also modify minDate I wrote by adding 1 day.

Comment: minDate={new Date((StartDate)+1)} this is not working for with plus one day, it will display all the dates

Comment: You should do `new Date().setDate(new Date(partnerStartDate).getDate() + 1);` take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/how-can-i-add-1-day-to-current-date/9989458)

Comment: few cases it's not working, attached image here