# How to add 1 day to current date in JS (UTC)?

Tags: javascript, date

I have the date as follows,

```
let date = '2024-03-11';
```

I want to add plus 1 day to above date

```
let newDate = mew Date(date); -> converting to local date -> 2024-03-10 (becoming -1)
newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
```

It worked well but the problem is I am getting the local date when I am using new Date() method which is converting my date to 2024-03-10

Can some one help me how to add 1 date to UTC date without getting it converted to local time zone.

Answer (score 1):

To add 1 day to a UTC date without it getting converted to the local timezone, you can directly manipulate the date string or use the Date.UTC method to ensure the operation is performed in UTC. Here's a method that modifies the date string and creates a new date object in UTC:

```js
let dateStr = '2024-03-11';

// Parse the date string and create a Date object in UTC
let date = new Date(Date.UTC(
  parseInt(dateStr.substring(0, 4), 10),  // Year
  parseInt(dateStr.substring(5, 7), 10) - 1, // Month (0-based)
  parseInt(dateStr.substring(8, 10), 10)   // Day
));

// Add 1 day in milliseconds
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

// Format the new date back to a string in YYYY-MM-DD format
let newDate = date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);

console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: This works fine but I want the final date in Date object format and if I try doing it using new Date(), then the date is getting changed to local date.

Answer (score 0):

for nodejs, you can use [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment):

```
const moment = require("moment");

let date = "2024-03-11";

let utcTime = moment.utc(date);

let plusTime = utcTime.add(1, "day");

let result = plusTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log(result);
// 2024-03-12
```

Comment: This works fine but I want the final date in Date object format and if I try doing it using new Date(), then the date is getting changed to local date.

Comment: There is no need to use the moment 3rd party package. You can use the Date class in Node.js too. Like the solutions by jun and Ikram Akbar.

Comment: Also in the NPM page you linked, it says "Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. In most cases, you should choose a different library."

Answer (score 0):

> It worked well but the problem is I am getting the local date when I
> am using new Date() method which is converting my date to 2024-03-10

No it isn't. Timestamps of the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, so:

```
new Date('2024-03-11');
```

creates a date for 2024-03-11T00:00:00Z.

However, *Date.prototype.toString* will produce a local timestamp, so it *appears* that the *Date* has been converted to local when it hasn't. Use *toISOString* to see the UTC date and time.

To add 1 to the date is exactly the same as [to a local date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989382/how-can-i-add-1-day-to-current-date/9989458#9989458), except UTC methods are used, e.g.

```js
let date = '2024-03-11';

// The built–in parser parses it as UTC by default
let d = new Date(date);
// 2024-03-11T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.toISOString());

// Add 1 to the day
d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
// 2024-03-12T00:00:00.000Z
console.log(d.toISOString());
```

TLDR;

Internally, Date objects represent an instant in time by storing a millisecond offset (called a time value) from 1 Jan 1970 UTC. A timestamp can then be produced from this time value using any numbering system, language (using BCP47 language tags), offset, timezone (using IANA representative locations) or calendar supported by ECMA-262 and ECMA-402.

See [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

The setUTCDate() method of Date instances changes the day of the month for this date according to universal time.

The getUTCDate() method of Date instances returns the day of the month for this date according to universal time.

```
let date = '2024-03-11';

let newDate = new Date(date);
newDate.setUTCDate(newDate.getUTCDate() + 1);

console.log(newDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // Output: 2024-03-12
```