# How to get "the day before a date" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

These two stack overflow questions ask a similar question, but their solution doesn't seem to work for me:
[Javascript Yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511323/javascript-yesterday)
[Javascript code for showing yesterday's date and todays date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495815/javascript-code-for-showing-yesterdays-date-and-todays-date)

Given a date, I need the date of the prior day (the day before). Here's a fiddle with the solution suggested above, and a scenario that doesn't work for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/s3dHV/

```
var date = new Date('04/28/2013 00:00:00');
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
alert('If today is ' + date + ' then yesterday is ' + yesterday);
```

For me, that alerts

> If today is Sun Apr 28 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
>   then yesterday is Monday May 27 2013 11:12:06 GMT-0400 (Eastern
>   Daylight Time).

Which is obviously incorrect. Why?

Comment: Reverse this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868241/javascript-date-1

Comment: The solution posted in that thread is exactly the same as the ones I've linked to...

Comment: Read comments: `date.setTime(date.getTime() + 86400000);` - venkatagiri

Comment: No need, Pointy's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You're making a whole new date.

```
var yesterday = new Date(date.getTime());
yesterday.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
```

That'll make you a *copy* of the first date. When you call `setDate()`, it just affects the day-of-the-month, not the whole thing. If you start with a copy of the original date, and then set the day of the month back, you'll get the right answer.

Comment: That's pretty goofy, if you ask me.  They should have called it `setDay()`, not `setDate()`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The sheer volume of things they should have done differently with the JavaScript `Date` object would (and probably does) fill volumes...

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, or `setDayOfMonth` or whatever. I have a soft spot however because the Date object (while having all sorts of problems) is really handy.

Comment: But being fair: One of the *right* things is that Pointy's code works even if `date` is the first day of a month, and so `date.getDate() - 1` is `0`. It will give you Feb 28th (or Feb 29th as appropriate) if `date` is March 1st, for instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes exactly - it makes doing things like building calendar displays really easy.

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
var date = new Date('04/28/2013 00:00:00');
var yesterday = new Date(date.getTime() - 24*60*60*1000);
```

Comment: Not all days are 24 hours long. We have daylight savings time in my country which means we have a 23 hour day once a year, and a 25 hour day once a year. Your code won't handle this correctly.

Comment: @Arbiter: don't forget about leap seconds!

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple function :

```
private _getYesterdayDate(): Date{
  const yesterday:Date = new Date();
  yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
  return yesterday;
}
```

The function works even if date is `the first day of a month`, and you used `date.getDate() - 1`, it will give you `last day in the previous month` as appropriate

Answer (score -4):

```
var allmonths = [
    '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'
];
var alldates = [
    '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
    '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
    '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31'
];

var today = "2014-12-25";   
var aDayBefore = new Date(today);
aDayBefore.setDate(aDayBefore.getDate() - 1);

document.write(aDayBefore.getFullYear() 
  + '-' + allmonths[aDayBefore.getMonth()] 
  + '-' + alldates[aDayBefore.getDate() - 1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.