# How to get the previous date in angular?

Tags: javascript

Please help me getting the previous dates in angular 4.

```
currentdate: Date;
this.currentdate = new Date();
console.log(this.datePipe.transform(this.currentdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
```

Here I got the date as 2017-11-13.

Now I need to get 2 days before date..

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401804/how-to-get-the-day-before-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "the day before a date" in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401804/how-to-get-the-day-before-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```js
let dte = new Date();
dte.setDate(dte.getDate() - 2);
console.log(dte.toString());
```

Comment: It give you just a number, what if we would like to get full date of yesterday ?

Comment: @Arash what's your problem?? Did you try to run it on your machine?? It gives `Tue Apr 16 2019 10:50:36 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` as output. Please make sure you know what's the output then only down vote any answer.
Or if needed ask your seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the `year -1` thing is always valid since February 29th issue. I think more accurate way is that

```
let aDate = new Date();
aDate.setDate(aDate.getDate() - numberOfDaysBefore);
```

replace 365 with number of days you want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct for javascript, this works in Angular:

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {
  // This gives you todays date.
  private dateToday: Date = new Date();
  // This also gives you todays date if you don't alter it on init.
  private dateYesterday: Date = new Date();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Alters the date
    this.dateYesterday = new Date(this.dateYesterday.setDate(this.dateYesterday.getDate() - 1));
  }

}
```