# how to subtract a day from current date in angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentDate = new Date();
    this.date = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'y-MM-dd');
    this.currentDate = this.date;
}
```

In the above code Im getting current date. The requirement is from this current date need to subtract a day means i can get yesterday.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260283/how-to-get-the-previous-date-in-angular/47260315#47260315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To output the date of yesterday, use the following block of code.

```js
export class DateComponent implements OnInit{
    datePipe = new DatePipe('en');
    public today?: Date;
    public yesterday?: string | null;

  ngOnInit(){
    // The following output tests the method 'getYesterday()'.
    console.log(this.getYesterday());
  }

  getYesterday(){
    this.today = new Date();
    this.today.setDate(this.today.getDate() - 1);
    // The following returns the formatted date.
    return this.yesterday = this.datePipe.transform(this.today, 'dd-MM-y');
  }
}
```

Comment: if it works for you , please accept and upvote.

Comment: my current date is in this format "2020-07-16" and would like to get yesterday in the same format as "2020-07-15"

Comment: I have edited the answer, please accept and upvote.

Comment: Please upvote the answer not down.

Comment: yes, I only upvoted your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This function adds any amount of days to the passed `Date` object. By passing `-1` we effectiviely subtract a day.

```
function addDays(a_oDate: Date, days: number): Date {
        a_oDate.setDate(a_oDate.getDate() + days);
        return a_oDate;
    }
    
    console.log(addDays(new Date(), - 1));
```

As a sidenote, try not to use pipes in your components, and refer to [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date) on more details on how to format your date.

Comment: Could you add comments or a bit explanation to your code.